# XSD XSOM : How to parse xs:anyAttribute using XSOM Java library?

Tags: java, xsd

I am trying to parse this complex type  but I am unable to get <xsd:anyAttribute element using XSOM JAVA.
I have tried getAttributeUses() and particle, but could not get it.

Any idea on how it can be parsed?

```
      <xsd:sequence>

      <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

      </xsd:sequence>

      <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this test XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="test">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

You need this code:

```
    XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();
    //parser.setErrorHandler(...);
    //parser.setEntityResolver(...);

    parser.parse(new File(...));

    XSSchemaSet sset = parser.getResult();
    XSComplexType xt = sset.getComplexType("http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd", "test");
    XSWildcard anyAttr = xt.getAttributeWildcard();
```

The key is the [getAttributeWildcard](http://xsom.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/xml/xsom/XSAttContainer.html#getAttributeWildcard%28%29) API.